# Proving that SU(2) is not isotropic

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isometry

I am thinking about problem 8-16 of the book *Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds*, by Lee. In it, we consider the manifold $G=SU(2)$, and the basis of its Lie algebra given by
$X=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
-1&0
\end{pmatrix}$, $Y=\begin{pmatrix}
0&i\\
i&0
\end{pmatrix}$, $Z=\begin{pmatrix}
i&0\\
0&-i
\end{pmatrix}$, and for each $a>0$ we let $g_a$ be the left-invariant metric such that $X,Y,aZ$ are an orthonormal basis of $T_eG$.

The exercise tells us to prove that if $a\neq1$, then $(G,g_a)$ is not isotropic. Using the previous exercise (8-15), we see that if $(G,g_a)$ was isotropic, then it would have constant sectional curvature (which implies for example that the Ricci tensor is a scalar multiple of the metric), and I think I am supposed to derive some contradiction from there. But I am not sure how to do it without lots of computations (I tried with graph coordinates of $\mathbb{S}^3\equiv SU(2)$ but it didn't look nice).

So that is the question, is there a way to prove that $(G,g_a)$ is not isotropic without taking local coordinates and computing lots of things, or alternatively, are there some local coordinates in which the computations are not very painful?